# Sharing a dedicated IP 

Tags: dedicated-hosting

I have 10 websites on an IP. I would like to share the IP among all the websites.How do I achieve this without having to run these websites on different port numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Host headers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=host+headers) for IIS.

Answer (score 3):

You use the "name-based virtual hosts" feature of the apache webserver:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/
Other webservers may or may not have a similar feature.